# Hosted Service Stopping

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a wcf service that is hosted via a windows service which is used to connect to a database and fetch information etc etc. The problem I have is that although the service works great it seems to die after restarting my test console app 4 times.

The first time I start the app all is ok and the same for restarting it the next two times however on the 4th time I start it up and get an endpoint not found exception. Upon investigation I found that my windows service was stopping itself with no errors after the 3rd start of the console app. There are no errors posted to my log file.

Does anyone have any pointers as to what this could be caused by?

Comment: Can you please hook some comments in service stop event and try to analyze it further. May be that could give some pointer. Ideally it should not happen.

Comment: Also look at SvcTraceViewer to dig into what's happening with the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue turned out to be a database connection not getting closed. As we have no event log currently I guessed that it could be caused by that and checked the methods.

Comment: Did the system automatically log an error to the application or system event log on the service's behalf?  Did you check there?

Comment: There was an error logged however it did not actually explain the issue in any detail. It only showed me the last method in the trace before the error occurred. From there I had to make an educated guess to find the source of the error.